# Roots of $x^2 -1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ with $m$ not a prime number

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Is there a way to calculate in general all of the solution of this equation $x^2-1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$ with $m$ not being prime? This question was posed to me by a friend who's currently taking a modern algebra class, and I tried a couple of things.

Simplifying the equation, we have $x^2 \equiv_m 1 \equiv_m m+1$, but that seems like as far as I can go. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

(I do not have any reason to believe this has a nice answer, by the way.)

Comment: Note that $x^2 \equiv_m 1$

Comment: Yes, you're correct.  Sorry about that. I'll edit appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Chinese remainder theorem, i.e. isomorphism $\mathbb Z_m\cong\mathbb Z_{p_1^{k_1}}\times\dots\times\mathbb Z_{p_n^{k_n}}$, where $m=p_1^{k_1}\dots p_n^{k_n}$ is the prime factorization. You thus need to solve $x^2\equiv1$ for each prime power $p_i^{k_i}$ independently.
2. If $p\neq2$ then the only solutions mod $p^k$ are $\pm1$. For $p=2$ and $k\geq2$ the solutions are $\pm1$ and $\pm1+2^{k-1}$ (this means: 1 solution for $k=1$, 2 solutions for $k=2$, 4 solutions for $k>2$).

Altogether there are thus $2^n$ solution, except when we have $2$ in the prime factorization.

Comment: This is extremely elegant. Thank you.