# Knowing prime factorization of $n$ determine number of solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How to determine number of solutions to $x^2 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ n)$, when I know prime factorization of $n$?

Comment: I assume the first step is to rewrite this as $n|(x+1)(x-1)$.

Comment: Hi @Machiawliczny, could you please give some more context? For example, do you know about the Chinese Remainder Theorem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Roots of $x^2 -1$ in $\mathbb{Z}\_m$ with $m$ not a prime number](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513695/roots-of-x2-1-in-mathbbz-m-with-m-not-a-prime-number). To tell you the truth I was surprised not to find an older dup.

Answer (score 3):

> Assume $n=2^ap_1^{a_1}\dots p_m^{a_m}$. Then the number of solutions are $2^m$ if $a=0$ or if $a=1$; $2^{m+1}$ if $a=2$ and $2^{m+2}$ if $a\geq 3$.

Taken from Vinogradov.

Proving this takes a chapter in Vinogradov's [book](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-isbn=0486495302&page=1&rh=i%3Aaps%2Cp_66%3A0486495302).

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if I can expand on my comment and try to prove [Ivan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/549021/17976).  As I said in the comment, if

$$x^2\equiv1\pmod n$$
$$x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)\equiv0 \pmod n$$
$$n|(x+1)(x-1)$$

For each prime power factor $p_m^{a_m},p\ne2$, either $p_m^{a_m}|x-1$ or $p_m^{a_m}|x+1$. If $n$ is odd, there are $2$ choices for each prime power.  Each set of choices gives $1$ solution $\pmod n$ by the Chinese remainder theorem, so there are $2^m$ possibilities.

$2$ is different since $x-1\equiv x+1\pmod 2$.  If $2^a|p$ and $a=1, x\equiv 1\pmod2$ is our only choice.  If $a=2$, then either $x-1$ or $x+1$ is divisible by $4$, so $2$ choices for $x\pmod4$.  If $a>2$, since $\gcd(x-1,x+1)|2$ we have either

$$2^{a-1}|x-1$$
$$x\equiv1\pmod{2^{a-1}}$$
$$x\equiv1,2^{a-1}+1\pmod{2^a}$$
$$\text{or}$$
$$2^{a-1}|x+1$$
$$x\equiv-1\pmod{2^{a-1}}$$
$$x\equiv-1,2^{a-1}-1\pmod{2^a}$$

so $4$ choices for $x\pmod{2^a}$.

Comment: All primes are odd except 2, which is the oddest of all. – D.E.Knuth.